Why do I need to install/update .NET 7.0 if I'm running .NET 8.0?
I've recently began learning C# at the FreeCodeCamp, and all has been going well.  I'm probably 2/3 into the course and now having trouble running their packaged code for the 'challenge'.  As I said, all has been going well, this is a procedure (download their premade code, open in vs2022, build, run) that I've done 7-8 times before, worked every time.  But now I'm getting an error on running (build is successful) that I need to install or update .NET 7.0.  But .NET 8.0 is found...any pointers would be appreciated.
I tried 'updating' .NET 8.0, but its a recent download itself, so, no change.

Sometimes the project that you are running use external libraries or packages, in this case nuget packages builded for an specific runtime. So maybe your project use packages that only run on 7. You can check if you have updates for those packages or just install the 7.0 sdk or runtime. Just guessing ok, you didn't provide a lot of details

Thanks, Hackerman, I'll try that.  What other details might prove useful?

Is the repo of the code on github? Can you share it?

No, but it can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/training/modules/challenge-project-work-variable-data-c-sharp/

Got it. So let's suppose that you are working with the Starter project. If you open the file Starter.csproj with a text editor, you can see the following on line 5 <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework> and it's possible that when the training came out .NET 7 was the latest version and that's why the content it's just a little bit outdated. Maybe you can upgrade it to .NET 8 using https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
